# string copy into malloc'd char array fails with segmentation fault

Tags: c, gdb, malloc, client-server

I am practicing a client-server application in C. In the application, the client first registers with the server and gets the `client_id` in return. Next time onwards, the client sends the messages to the server prepending the `client_id` to the message. Below code snippet is from the server, where after receiving the message, the server retrieves the `client_id` from the message, which is a 3 char long string with start address as 1 and end address as 4 from the message array. eg. In the message `"1001CLIENT:001:MESSAGE:01"`, '1' at location 0 is for some purpose, "001" is the `client_id` and `"CLIENT:001:MESSAGE:01"` is the message from the client.

```
char *create_dynamic_string(int str_size)
{
        char *dyn_string = malloc(str_size*sizeof(char));
        if(!dyn_string)
        {
                printf("Dynamic string could not be created");
                return NULL;
        }
        dyn_string[0] = '\0';
        return dyn_string;
}

void free_dynamic_string(char *dyn_string)
{
        free(dyn_string);
}

//char *message is dynamically allocated char array.
char *retrieve_client_id(char *message)
{
        char *client_id;
        int i;
        client_id = create_dynamic_string(CLIENT_ID_SIZE + 1);

        if(!client_id)
        {
                printf("Client_id is NULL");
                return NULL;
        }
        //for(i = 1; i < (CLIENT_ID_SIZE + 1); i++)
        //      client_id[i-1] = message[i];

        //strncpy(client_id, message + 1, CLIENT_ID_SIZE);

        memcpy(client_id, message + 1, CLIENT_ID_SIZE);

        client_id[CLIENT_ID_SIZE] = '\0';
        printf("client_id retrieved=%s", client_id);
        return client_id;
}
```

The server accepts a connection from the clients and processes the messages in different threads. The working on multi-threading and processing of the messages is tested successfully. Below code compiled successfully and works most of the times. But some times it ends up in segmentation fault at `memcpy()` in `retrieve_client_id()`.  I am not able to figure out why is it failing this way.

I used `gdb` to get more info. This is as below.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004017ef in retrieve_client_id (message=0x1b904f40 "1000CLIENT:000:MESSAGE:02") at src/server.c:46
46              memcpy(client_id, message + 1, CLIENT_ID_SIZE);
(gdb) print message
$1 = 0x1b904f40 "1000CLIENT:000:MESSAGE:02"
(gdb) print message+1
$2 = 0x1b904f41 "000CLIENT:000:MESSAGE:02"
(gdb) print CLIENT_ID_SIZE
$3 = 3
(gdb) print client_id
$4 = 0xffffffffcc0008c0 <Address 0xffffffffcc0008c0 out of bounds>
(gdb)
```

Need help in understanding what exactly might be happening when the application is failing. I have verified that the `malloc` was successful and `client_id` was not NULL. As you can see the commented code, I also tried with `strcpy()` and also copying the chars from source to dest array one by one. But there also I saw the failures.

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: I am not casting it anyways. If you see in the gdb logs, the value of CLIENT_ID_SIZE is 3.

Comment: oh is it? you seem very confident about it? what about `char *dyn_string = (char *)malloc(str_size*sizeof(char));` then? :-)

Comment: Oops, missed it. :D I tried without casting as well. Issue is still seen.

Comment: why don't you put a null check for incoming `message` pointer?

Comment: Are you posting gdb info of same thread that got segfault? As you said there are multiple threads, so verify that. Also, print value of  `client_id` before and after allocation function.

Comment: The message pointer is populated fine. The control will come to retrieve_client_id() only when the message was there. So I have not added any check here.

Comment: @rohan  I have used the core dump generated after the code seg faulted. I suppose it was the dump for the failed thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that `create_dynamic_string` and `retrieve_client_id` are in different compilation units, and that you don't have correct prototype for the former visible when the latter is compiled.

This address `0xffffffffcc0008c0` looks like a reasonable heap address `0xcc0008c0` with extra bits tacked on.

Add this line:

```
extern char *create_dynamic_string(int);
```

just above definition of `retrieve_client_id`.

If that fixes the problem (it should), then add prototype for `create_dynamic_string` to appropriate header file, and `#include` it into the source that defines `retrieve_client_id`.

> I did not understand why it did not give compilation error

In C, an undeclared function is *assumed* to have the following prototype:

```
int undeclared(...);
```

As such, any of the calls below will not be rejected:

```
int x = undeclared();
int y = undeclared(1);
char *z = undeclared(1, 2, 3);
```

You can *ask* GCC to warn you about missing prototypes specifically with `-Wmissing-prototypes`, but the best practice is to compile with `-Wall` and `-Werror`. The latter will not let you ignore warnings and *force* you to fix them.

Adding `-Wextra` is also recommended, although it does sometimes give false-positive warnings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the prototype for create_dynamic_string(). I had missed the #include for the source file where create_dynamic_string() prototype was available. And not it looks like working fine. But I did not understand why it did not give compilation error.  Can you please explain.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Will use -Wall and -Werror going forward. I wanted to understand what exactly was happening at runtime? Why memcpy() was failing here if the address 0xffffffffcc0008c0 was a reasonable heap address.